# React AJAX запросы. Как лучше их использовать?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, state

Новичок в React и появилась задача - нужно сделать AJAX запрос и эти данные вывести. 
Смотрел примеры реализации и во всех этих примерах запросы выполнялись в `App.js`, после чего состояние передавалось в дочерние компоненты.
Сам вопрос: Почему я не могу делать запрос в каком-либо другом компоненте с использованием хука `useEffect` и записывать это всё в локальный state.

Comment: Кто говорил что нельзя делать запрос в дочерних компонентах?

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов вот поэтому и спрашиваю. Что ни читал - везде запрос идёт в App.js. Решил уточнить. Спасибо, а то думал, что совершать запросы в дочерних компонентах ошибка

Comment: В App.js запрос отправляется для того чтобы потом их правильно делить между дочерними компонентами. Но если вам нужно получить к примеру имя пользователя это уже можно отправить в самом компоненте.

Comment: Если конечно не нужно потом это имя которое получили с запроса использовать еще в других местах.